# Split array keys and its values into new vars

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know exactly the programming terminology but I have a lot of arrays like this

```
$arr[3][4][0]='sample value A';
$arr[3][4][1]='sample value B';
...and so on
```

They have 3 keys each, so I was wondering if PHP has any function to split into values, keys and details of each var like this:

```
$keyA[0]=3;
$keyB[0]=4;
$keyC[0]=0;
$strg[0]='sample value A';

$keyA[1]=3;
$keyB[1]=4;
$keyC[1]=1;
$strg[1]='sample value B';
```

without doing a `foreach` inside a `foreach` to grab the values ?

Comment: what would be the purpose of it, I mean is it for a specific use? you could look into array_keys maybe, but you would still have to do some code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array[3][4][0] = 'sample value A';
$array[3][4][1] = 'sample value B';

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($iter as $key => $value) {
    $keys[$iter->getDepth()] = $key;    
    if(!$iter->callHasChildren()) {
        $keyA[] = $keys[0];
        $keyB[] = $keys[1];
        $keyC[] = $keys[2];
        $strg[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($keyA);
print_r($keyB);
print_r($keyC);
print_r($strg);
```

Answer (score 3):

try using `foreach()` don't know any function can help

```
foreach($a as $k=> $v) {
  foreach($v as $k1=> $v1) {
       foreach($v1 as $k2=> $v2) {
        $keyA[] = $k;
        $keyB[] = $k1;
        $keyC[] = $k2;
        $strg[] = $v2;
      }
  }
}

print_r($keyA); //Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 )
print_r($keyB); //Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 4 ) 
print_r($keyC); //Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) 
print_r($strg); //Array ( [0] => sample value A [1] => sample value B )
```

Comment: That's exactly what am doing :) Was just wondering whether PHP has any function to do this in a different way.

Comment: i think not any function in my mind it's a simplest way